# Adding data to table form sql and storing back to new database

Tags: php, sql, database

Its bit confusing for me to also explain this but still i will try my best to explain.

as i am new with php and mysql i don't understand how to get this done.

please have a look at the image and please guide me with my stuck point.

[image: see this image i hope it explain what i need]

in short, what i need is:  How to do this database connectivity and updating etc !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to select the data from the 1st table with a query like this:

```
<?php
//connect to the database server
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Dropje123") or  die(mysql_error()); 
//select the database 
$objDB = mysql_select_db("NAW"); 
//select which data you want to get.
$sql           = "SELECT * FROM tb1";
$objQuery      = mysql_query($sql);
$objResult     = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);  
?>
```

Then you need to create a table with html like this:

```
<form id="form" action="insert.php" method="post">
<table width="700" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th width="20"> <div align="center">Roll_no </div></th>  
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Name </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Class </div></th>
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Marks </div></th>
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Subject1 </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Sub2 </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Sub3 </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Adress </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Phone </div></th> 
</th>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td><input type="hidden" name="Roll_No" value="<?=$objResult["Roll_No"];?>"></td>  
<td><div  align="center"><?=$objResult["Roll_No"];?></div></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Name" value="<?=$objResult["Name"];?>"></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="Class" size="20"></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="Marks" size="20"></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="Subject1" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Sub2" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Sub3" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Adress" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Phone" size="20"></td>  
</tr> 
<button type="submit" id="send">Verzenden</button>
</form>
```

This will send the inserted data to insert.php. The insert.php would look something like this:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Insert</title> 
</head>  
<body>      
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('yourdb') or die (mysql_error());

$Roll_No           =    $_POST['Roll_No'];
$Name              =    $_POST['Name'];
$Class             =    $_POST['Class'];
$Marks             =    $_POST['Marks'];
$Subject1         =    $_POST['Subject1'];
$Sub2              =    $_POST['Sub2'];
$Sub3              =    $_POST['Sub3'];
$Adress           =    $_POST['Adress'];
$Phone             =    $_POST['Phone'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO db2 (Roll_No, Name, Class, Marks, Subject1, Sub2, Sub3, Adress, Phone) VALUES ('".$Roll_No."', '".$Name."', '".$Class."', '".$Marks."','".$Subject1."', '".$Sub2."', '".$Sub3."', '".$Adress."', '".$Phone."')") or die (mysql_error());

if ($sql === false) {

die (mysql_error());

}

else {

echo 'The data is inserted in the database!.<br><br>
}
?>
</body>  
</html>
```

You will just have to edit this code a bit to fit your needs. I hope this helped and good luck!

EDIT:
To display all the rows from the database you can use a for loop like this:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;  
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))  
{  
$i++;  
?>  
<tr>  
<td><input type="text" name="Roll_No" value="<?=$objResult["Roll_No"];?>"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Name" value="<?=$objResult["Name"];?>"></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="Class" size="20"></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="Marks" size="20"></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="Subject1" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Sub2" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Sub3" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Adress" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Phone" size="20"></td>  
</tr> 
<?php  
}  
?>
```

NOTE: If you use this for loop you will have to delete the following row from the sql section or it will not display the first row from your database:

```
$objResult     = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
```

NOTE2: This will only display all the rows from the database but if you submit this it will just insert 1 row in the 2nd database. You will need to get some kind of loop in the insert.php to but I not sure how that works.

For some explanation of the SQL section you could take a look at [this tutorial!](http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson20.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot, a last issue. Is there a specific loop method to call so i don't need to create table of 100 record and that loop does with above function included in it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot... i will have a lot at the url you gave.. but can you tell me the code you provided -  $sql           = "SELECT * FROM tb1";
$objQuery      = mysql_query($sql);
$objResult     = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);  

what will be the full SQL code ? and does this need to be separate file or in the main file we can include this as well ??

Comment: @devilcrab, I edited my answer again. The SQL section you can just add to the top of the code in your main file.

Comment: i used this code , but this only updates last record to database but not the full record like 1-6 all...  :(  any help ?

Comment: As I said in my note this will only insert 1 row to the database. You will need to get some kind of loop in the insert.php to insert every row but I am not sure how to do that so you might have to google a bit with that.

Comment: here is a question in continuity to this questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917361/adding-multiple-row-record-data-to-database-in-php-and-mysql

Comment: Please do not suggest to beginners that they use mysql_query. It's a deprecated interface, it's dangerous if not used correctly, and it's going away in future versions of PHP. You're doing more harm than good here. You didn't even bother to [escape your SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) which is like handing a gun to someone without telling them it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the basics step for you if your a beginner in using php and mysql..

---

**MSQLI**

*FIRST : SET UP CONFIGURATION FOR DATABASE USER,PASS,HOST,DBNAME*

```
$conn = new mysqli('database_server','database_username','database_password','database_name');
```

*SECOND : Create a Query(you may insert,select,update,delete your query here)..*

```
$result= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

*FINAL : SHOWN RECORDS USING MYSQL FUNCTIONS LIKE..*

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['dabatase_columnname'];
    echo $row['database_columnname'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! and can you tell me that there is a function i think in php or sql so we can show like 100 first record automatically then like after 24 hrs next 101-200 record and so on.. so how to do that ?

Comment: refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html  using limit to display specific numbers of records.

Comment: Please do not suggest to beginners that they use `mysql_query`. It's a deprecated interface, it's dangerous if not used correctly, and it's going away in future versions of PHP. You're doing more harm than good here.

Answer (score 0):

```
//For connection setup
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//For localhost
//DB choosing
mysql_select_db("sampldb",$con);
//For inserting
mysql_query("insert into table1 (name,rollno) values ('$name','$rollno')");
mysql_query("insert into table2 (name,rollno) values ('$name','$rollno')");

Dont update,insert the values in both the table at the time of inserting.So it is easy for you.
```

Comment: Please do not suggest to beginners that they use `mysql_query`. It's a deprecated interface, it's dangerous if not used correctly, and it's going away in future versions of PHP. You're doing more harm than good here. This short example has a [gigantic SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) that represents, in a nutshell, why you should not use `mysql_query`.